# How can we parse an XML with ISO-8859-15 encoding?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing

I was using UTF-8 encoded xml for parsing using NSXMLParser. But some of the special characters were causing problems and so decided to use ISO-8859-15 encoding.

But after that the parser doesnt even start parsing and is giving the error 31 - NSXMLParserUnknownEncodingError. What should I do now? Is it possible by anyway we can parse a ISO-8859-15 encoded xml in iphone? Will libxml or anyother parser provide support for this encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself. We decided to use the UTF-8 encoding for the xml and parsed it using the NSXMLParser. But before the parsing we did the following steps.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://the url for parsing"]];

NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Then after that some italian characters(3-4) were still causing problems and we manually replaced them after getting the result.

Now everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

NSISOLatin1StringEncoding is wrong, e.g. € can't encode.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
...
```

xCode:

```
NSString *xmlFileAsString = nil; //read xml file

NSStringEncoding iso88599 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingISOLatin9); 

NSData *data = [xmlFileAsString dataUsingEncoding:iso88599 allowLossyConversion:YES];

xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadMemory([data bytes], (int)[data length], NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_COMPACT | XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);

if (doc == NULL) {
...
```

get string from xml: (e.g. USAdditions.m)

```
+ (NSString *)stringWithXmlString:(xmlChar *)str free:(BOOL)freeOriginal {
    if (!str) return nil;
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:(char*)str encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (freeOriginal)
        xmlFree(str);
    return string;
}
```

Comment: hmm... so what _is_ the solution?